How can I know the complexity of my conceptual game and solving it with an algorithm?
I made a really simple card game where you and your opponent have 6 cards and in a turn you can use only one of them and it will be discarded.
The cards have a value and an effect.
The cards, with their respective value and effect, are:
1 - Destroy an enemy card of your choice;
2 - Add 1 to the value multiplier, thus doubling, tripling...etc.;
3 - Swap your cards with the opponent's;
4 - Obtain a Gem, you can no longer use this effect (temporary name, but still allows you to reuse a card);
5 - Make both players' points negative;
6 - Reuse this card once more, the effect applies only once.
When you play a card, you gain points based on the value of it. When everyone played all the cards and have more points than the opponents, wins.
I am curious to know how can I solve this game, so knowing what moves at 100% are bad (like using the Negative Points card on Turn 1) and what moves are the absolute best and the notions I need to learn for doing that.
Thank you so much and have a good weekend!

Check out adversarial search algorithms such as minimax and alpha–beta pruning.

Thank you so much!
